# I can't range the cells interval

Tags: vba, algorithm

I created a code so that each time a record was inserted into a line the program would detect the last line with values (assigned to the variable "k") and select a specific interval for the graph to update, but an error occurs, could someone help me ?

VBA Code:

```
  Public Sub Chart_Update()

Dim k As Long

k = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range ("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:K" & k & ",J2:J" & k & "K2:K & k")

'Error there!!
----------------------
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
"AC_Offset_Registers!"$B$2:$B$" & k ,AC_Offset_Registers!"$E$2:$E$" & k ,AC_Offset_Registers!"$I$2:$I$" & k ,AC_Offset_Registers!"$J$2:$J$" & k,AC_Offset_Registers!"$K$2:$K$" & k" _
)
-----------------
End Sub
```

I know the variable "k" is in a comment but I don't know where I should put the quotes so the syntax is correct

Comment: First quote starts a string and the following quote ends a string. So your first string is `"AC_Offset_Registers!"` but what you actually want is `"AC_Offset_Registers!"B$2:$B$"` beeing your first string and that should be concatenated with `&` and the variable and another `&` and the next string.

Comment: please redo the code as you are saying, I can't understand

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Range("B2:B&k,E2:E&k,I2:I&k,J2:J&k,K2:K&k")
```

is no valid syntax and needs to be changed to

```
Range("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:I" & k & ",J2:J" & k & ",K2:K" & k)
```

or shorter

```
Range("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:K" & k)
```

The same technique needs to be applied to your other range.

Finally you might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: could you tell me what this line would look like then?

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
"AC_Offset_Registers!$B$2:$B$&k,AC_Offset_Registers!$E$2:$E$&k,AC_Offset_Registers!$I$2:$I$&k,AC_Offset_Registers!$J$2:$J$&k,AC_Offset_Registers!$K$2 :$K$&k" _
)

Comment: @KhallP Give it a try yourself first please. Try to adapt what I showed above, it is not that difficult. If you get stuck or errors please edit your original question and show your attempt.

Comment: I don't really know how to do the last part, the syntax is wrong :(


Public Sub Chart_Update()

Dim k As Long

k = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range ("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:K" & k & ",J2:J" & k & "K2:K & k")
error there
--------------------------------------------
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
"AC_Offset_Registers!"$B$2:$B$" & k ,AC_Offset_Registers!"$E$2:$E$" & k ,AC_Offset_Registers!"$I$2:$I$" & k ,AC_Offset_Registers!"$J$2: $J$" & k,AC_Offset_Registers!"$K$2:$K$" & k" _
)
-------------------------
End Sub

Comment: have a look, after every `k` you need an `& "` to start the next string. The `&` concatenates a string with a variable. Please note that code in comments gets unreadable that is why I asked you to edit your original question to add code.